# Angular and Bootstrapstudio bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css) returned a Promise

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-studio

I recently developed a form in Bootstrap studio  that I would know like to use in my angular application. I generated a component to host the exported html code form bootstrap studio and I have placed it all into a components file. I now have a structure that looks something like this is my file directory.

[image]

index.html, login.html, profile.html, register.html and table.html all all the html files generated by Bootstrap studio. I would like to use the profile HTML in my app so I copied that code into my user-profiles.component.html file so that it looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Profile - Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary p-0">
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column p-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center sidebar-brand m-0" href="#">
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"><i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i></div>
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"><span>Brand</span></div>
                </a>
                <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-light" id="accordionSidebar">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="profile.html"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span>Profile</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="table.html"><i class="fas fa-table"></i><span>Table</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.html"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i><span>Login</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="register.html"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><span>Register</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline"><button class="btn rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle" type="button"></button></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-white shadow mb-4 topbar static-top">
                    <div class="container-fluid"><button class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3" id="sidebarToggleTop" type="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
                        <form class="form-inline d-none d-sm-inline-block mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                            <div class="input-group"><input class="bg-light form-control border-0 small" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
                                <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-primary py-0" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-nowrap ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown d-sm-none no-arrow"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                                    <form class="form-inline mr-auto navbar-search w-100">
                                        <div class="input-group"><input class="bg-light form-control border-0 small" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
                                            <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-primary py-0" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                                <div class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span><i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in">
                                        <h6 class="dropdown-header">alerts center</h6>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="mr-3">
                                                <div class="bg-primary icon-circle"><i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div><span class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</span>
                                                <p>A new monthly report is ready to download!</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="mr-3">
                                                <div class="bg-success icon-circle"><i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div><span class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</span>
                                                <p>$290.29 has been deposited into your account!</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="mr-3">
                                                <div class="bg-warning icon-circle"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div><span class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</span>
                                                <p>Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a><a class="text-center dropdown-item small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                                <div class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i><span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span></a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in">
                                        <h6 class="dropdown-header">alerts center</h6>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3"><img class="rounded-circle" src="./assets/img/avatars/avatar4.jpeg">
                                                <div class="bg-success status-indicator"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                                <div class="text-truncate"><span>Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a problem I've been having.</span></div>
                                                <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Emily Fowler - 58m</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3"><img class="rounded-circle" src="./assets/img/avatars/avatar2.jpeg">
                                                <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                                <div class="text-truncate"><span>I have the photos that you ordered last month!</span></div>
                                                <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Jae Chun - 1d</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3"><img class="rounded-circle" src="./assets/img/avatars/avatar3.jpeg">
                                                <div class="bg-warning status-indicator"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                                <div class="text-truncate"><span>Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with the progress so far, keep up the good work!</span></div>
                                                <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Morgan Alvarez - 2d</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                                            <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3"><img class="rounded-circle" src="./assets/img/avatars/avatar5.jpeg">
                                                <div class="bg-success status-indicator"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                                <div class="text-truncate"><span>Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...</span></div>
                                                <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Chicken the Dog · 2w</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a><a class="text-center dropdown-item small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="shadow dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown"></div>
                            </li>
                            <div class="d-none d-sm-block topbar-divider"></div>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                                <div class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><span class="d-none d-lg-inline mr-2 text-gray-600 small">Valerie Luna</span><img class="border rounded-circle img-profile" src="./assets/img/avatars/avatar1.jpeg"></a>
                                    <div
                                        class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Profile</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Settings</a>
                                        <a
                                            class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Activity log</a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a></div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h3 class="text-dark mb-4">Profile</h3>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card mb-3">
                            <div class="card-body text-center shadow"><img class="rounded-circle mb-3 mt-4" src="./assets/img/dogs/image2.jpeg" width="160" height="160">
                                <div class="mb-3"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Change Photo</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header py-3">
                                <h6 class="text-primary font-weight-bold m-0">Projects</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">Server migration<span class="float-right">20%</span></h4>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mb-3">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%;"><span class="sr-only">20%</span></div>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">Sales tracking<span class="float-right">40%</span></h4>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mb-3">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%;"><span class="sr-only">40%</span></div>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">Customer Database<span class="float-right">60%</span></h4>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mb-3">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"><span class="sr-only">60%</span></div>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">Payout Details<span class="float-right">80%</span></h4>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mb-3">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;"><span class="sr-only">80%</span></div>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">Account setup<span class="float-right">Complete!</span></h4>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mb-3">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;"><span class="sr-only">100%</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="row mb-3 d-none">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card text-white bg-primary shadow">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row mb-2">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p class="m-0">Peformance</p>
                                                <p class="m-0"><strong>65.2%</strong></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-rocket fa-2x"></i></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-white-50 small m-0"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>&nbsp;5% since last month</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card text-white bg-success shadow">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row mb-2">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p class="m-0">Peformance</p>
                                                <p class="m-0"><strong>65.2%</strong></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-rocket fa-2x"></i></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-white-50 small m-0"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>&nbsp;5% since last month</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card shadow mb-3">
                                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                                        <p class="text-primary m-0 font-weight-bold">User Settings</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <form>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="username"><strong>Username</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="user.name" name="username"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="email"><strong>Email Address</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="user@example.com" name="email"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="first_name"><strong>First Name</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" name="first_name"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="last_name"><strong>Last Name</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Doe" name="last_name"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save Settings</button></div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card shadow">
                                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                                        <p class="text-primary m-0 font-weight-bold">Contact Settings</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <form>
                                            <div class="form-group"><label for="address"><strong>Address</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Sunset Blvd, 38" name="address"></div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="city"><strong>City</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Los Angeles" name="city"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="country"><strong>Country</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="USA" name="country"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save&nbsp;Settings</button></div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                        <p class="text-primary m-0 font-weight-bold">Forum Settings</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group"><label for="signature"><strong>Signature</strong><br></label><textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="signature"></textarea></div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-switch"><input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="custom-control-label" for="formCheck-1"><strong>Notify me about new replies</strong></label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save Settings</button></div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="bg-white sticky-footer">
            <div class="container my-auto">
                <div class="text-center my-auto copyright"><span>Copyright © Brand 2020</span></div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div><a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/bs-init.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and my user-profiles.component.ts file looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profiles',
  templateUrl: './user-profiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profiles.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfilesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

so I believe that this should still work but I am getting the following error

```
ERROR in HostResourceLoader: loader(C:/Users/ipadc/Dropbox/References.Data/NWU werk/Projekvak/Code/Final-honors-app/src/app/components/user-profiles/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css) returned a Promise
```

I have no idea what this error means or how to resolve it any tips would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use any one of the bootstrap version.
To remove ,

```
  "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          ***"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"*** --> this line
        ],
```

from the angular.json

or else

To remove

Profile - Brand
    ****** --> this  line from your code